# Why do I see a Windows 7 style window here?

Tags: windows-10

When I toggle fullscreen in Command Prompt with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, for a split second, the following flashes onto the screen:

[image]

Any explanation as to why I'm seeing this? Is this the case with other machines?

Comment: Alt-Tab doesn't toggle fullscreen in cmd.

Comment: Most likely Windows 10 still has the same “Basic” theme, even though there’s no longer any transparency in the default theme. And yes, I can see this happening as well.

Comment: Is this the case with other machines?   Not here in Windows 10 or Windows 11 (hard drive so a wee bit of delay).   Try replacing your video driver.